# Несколько таймеров в switch

Tags: jquery, таймер, settimeout

При клике на элемент в зависимости от условия (case) выполняеться функция из таймером (поочередное появление блоков). Нужно прерывать уже запущенные таймеры при переключении между условиями (case).

```
$(".link").click(function(){
        switch(true){
            case // условие:
            $(function(){
                $('.block').each(function (){
                    timeoutID1 = setTimeout(function () {
                        // действие
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
            break;
            case // условие:
            $(function(){
                $('.block').each(function (){
                    timeoutID2 = setTimeout(function () {
                        // действие
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
            break;
            case // условие:
            $(function(){
                $('.block').each(function (){
                    timeoutID3 = setTimeout(function () {
                        // действие
                    }, 2000);
                });
            });
            break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема? Есть функция, которая и создана для остановки таймеров - `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

Храните ваши таймеры в массиве и на каждом `case` чистите их, либо в каждом блоке очищайте не связанные с этим блоком таймеры:

```
clearTimeout(timeoutID2);
clearTimeout(timeoutID3);
timeoutID1 = setTimeout(function () {
    // действие
}, 2000);
```

Хотя код у вас довольно странный. Зачем в цикле присваивать все таймеры одной переменной? Она в итоге только один таймер и будет хранить. Поэтому, лучше будет держать их в массивах, а потом уже чистить массивы таймеров для конкретного условия

Comment: можна пример с массивами?

Comment: я бы вообще саму функцию в объект положил, и индексом бы сделал условие case